# Adding OR condition in VersionOne Query API

Tags: python, api, postman, plotly-dash, versionone

I am querying the V1 (/query.v1 API) via Python/Dash to get all stories tagged with certain tags.

The Where criteria for API Body is

```
"where": {
    "TaggedWith":"Search-Module" ,
    "Team.ID": "Team:009"
},
```

but I wanted to add OR criteria (something like assets tagged with "Search-Module OR Result-Module")

```
"where": {
    "TaggedWith":"Search-Module;Result-Module" ,
    "Team.ID": "Team:009"
},
```

The documentation in V1 is very basic and I am not able to find the correct way for additional criteria.

https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Sample_Code/Tour_of_query.v1

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: There is an `or` operator: `|`, see https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Learn_the_API/Data_API/Queries/where

Comment: that is for REST (GET) API, there you can add AND where=Team.Name='myTeamName'&&CreateDate>='2020-01-01' as you mentioned     OR as given. In Query API you have to send (POST) query as body to get the response. I have problem there.. we are working with Query API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set alternative values to a variable in the `with` property and use that variable within the `where` or `filter` property values:

```
{
  "from": "Story",
  "select": [
    "Name"
  ],
  "where": {
    "Team.ID": "Team:009",
    "TaggedWith": "$tags"
  },
  "with": {
    "$tags": [
        "Search-Module",
        "Result-Module"
    ]
  }
}
```

As an option, you can use `,` (comma) as a separator:

```
"with": {
    "$tags": "Search-Module,Result-Module"
}
```

The last example of the multi-value variable (but for the `rest-1.v1` endpoint) has been found in the [VersionOne Grammar](https://github.com/versionone/Grammars/blob/master/V1FilterContext.g) project.

Comment: Worked fine, thanks. For future me, you can also add "find": "2021",
 "findin":
    [
      "SecurityScope.Name"
    ], to find/filter items from the results..